# Awaiting for serviceWorker register not returning activated worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I am registering new service worker for receiving push notifications:

```
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/js/serviceWorker-bundle.js", {
  scope: "/"
});

console.log(registration.active);
```

But console.log printing `null` what means worker is not still registered. It worked few hours and now it does not work. Why `await` is not waiting until worker is registered and active so I can do subscribe?

Comment: Could this be part of the problem? _The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function._ from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await. If not, please provide a complete/working code sample.

Comment: Nope I have async in parent function.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I recommend you mention that in your question just to cut down on the obvious stuff.

Comment: It may be enlightening to add a  `.catch()` so that you can catch any errors that may be produced within the promise.

Comment: Catch is empty I am using try catch

Comment: You should probably add a _small, complete, runnable_ code snippet (not necessarily including the service worker JS) that reproduces the problem. Often problems are in the part of the code you don't think is relevant, so creating something that is **small** but reproduces the problem is useful for you (you might see it) and for others trying to help.

Comment: agree with @KevinReid - You've asked for help while asking us to guess about the way you are going about things. (didn't mention enclosing async func, didn't mention try/catch, provide no error conditions, did not provide explanation of the differences between "a few hours ago" and this code, etc.). I've voted to close until you provide [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as suggested in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)